# juju add a unit to a pending agent

Tags: juju

I do have a service with a unit pending because theres no machines to add that unit.

After I add a machine, how to assign the pending unit to that machine?

I've searched under google and in the official documentations, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a manual registration process.

It might be easier to add the machine first, THEN add the service with `--to <machine>`. I don't know how to connect the pending service to the existing machine.

The other thing you can do is to deploy a service to a new LXC container on the machine, like this:

```
juju deploy charm --to lxc:<machine>
```